# Macro with multi condition in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I need to create a macro to color all cells contains ("*1/*") and colored 13 in condition if the file contains word "Parent" in D2
The below macro work but can be applicable to any file without considering the main condition "Parent"
Could you please help

```
For Each rngCell In Range("D2:S1000")
If D2 Like "*Parent*" Then          'otherwise do nothing
If rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex <> 13 And rngCell.Value Like "*1/*" Then
rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
End If
Next
```

I tried the above macro but it modifies all col without considering the main condition "Parent" as you see it color the col but for Parent data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjcKr.png)

Comment: soryy would like to say not colored 13

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76343596/edit) to add information or make corrections

Comment: 1) You are missing one `End If`  2) Is there a reason you are not using conditonnal formatting?

Comment: I added the end if but still can modify any file without considering word "Parent" and I am not using conditional formating because this small part of big macro I am using

Comment: `If rngCell.Value Like "*Parent*" Then` maybe?

Comment: so I changed to the following but still can color all cells without considering the worls "parent" or "Repair", it's still can color all

Comment: For Each rngCell In Range("F2:S1000")
        
        If D2 Like "*Repair*" Then Stop
                If rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex <> 13 And rngCell.Value Like "*1/*" Then
                          rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
                End If
              '  End If
                Next

Comment: Consider uploading some screencaps or sample data and expected outcome to http://imgur.com and linking to them here

Comment: Province Vendor Location Group Calendar Interval 21/05/2023 22/05/2023 23/05/2023 24/05/2023 25/05/2023 26/05/2023
ON U23-ON XXXX A-NI - DTH SFU Residential Repair AM  0/2  3/3  4/4  4/4  3/3  3/3
ON U23-ON   PM  3/3  3/3  4/4  4/4  4/4  4/4
ON U23-ON   EV  0/0  2/2  0/0  0/0  1/1  1/1
ON U23-ON   C/A  3/5  8/8  8/8  8/8  8/8  8/8
ON U23-ON  B-NI - DTH SFU Residential Install AM   1/1  1/1  1/1  0/1  1/1
ON U23-ON   PM   1/1  1/1  1/1  0/1  1/1
ON U23-ON   EV   1/1  0/0  0/0  0/0  0/0
ON U23-ON   C/A   3/3  1/1  1/1  0/2  2/2

Comment: I am not able to attached scrrenshot

Comment: above data should not be modified because excel file contains "Repair" but if file contains "Parent" then all cells 1/ should be colored

Answer (score 2):

D2? If you add "Option Explicit" at the beginning of your code, you will see that "D2" is wrong. You hade to write Range("D2").

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim rngCell As Range
If Range("D2") Like "*Parent*" Then          'otherwise do nothing
    For Each rngCell In Range("D2:S1000")
        If rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex <> 13 And rngCell.Value Like "*1/*" Then
            rngCell.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
        End If
    Next rngCell
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If this is the solution, you take the `If` outside the loop, since the cell is not changing.

Comment: Emilio, I "corrected" the code now.